# Replace text inside various delimiters (eg: brackets, quotes)

Tags: text-editing

I often do some testing implementation with hardcoded values which I later want to change. Like

```
ref = open('specific-file-name')
```

Which I would like to change into

```
ref = open(fname)
```

I'm used to vim and there I can type `ci(fname` assuming that point is inside the brackets. (`ci(` stands for replace inner brackets).

How can I achieve something like 'replace inner ' in emacs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Using `expand-region`

I would recommend installing the [`expand-region`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) package (available on Melpa too). It would be useful for editing situations mentioned in your example and lot more.

`expand-region` is intelligent. Based on the major mode, it will try to figure out what you are trying to select. I don't know from which language you have the example snippet so I will use your example code snippet and slightly modify it for Python (remove ;). So my below explanation is with the below code snippet in a `python-mode` buffer.

```py
ref = open('specific-file-name')
```

**If point is next to a single quote**

*The black vertical rectangles below indicate how the cursor will look.*

```
# point on left of left quote, the cursor is hiding the quote under it
ref = open(▮specific-file-name') 

# point on left of right parenthesis, the cursor is hiding the parenthesis under it       
ref = open('specific-file-name'▮
```

In either case, when you do `M-x er/expand-region`, `'specific-file-name'` will get selected and you can then hit `DEL` (or backspace) to delete the selection.

If you have `delete-selection-mode` enabled (I like to have that enabled personally), you can start typing away after doing the selection and that will overwrite the selection.

Of course, if you use `er/expand-region` a lot, you would bind it to a short key binding. I like to bind it to `C-\`. So with point next to a single quote: **`C-\fname`** will give me `ref = open(fname);`

[image]

**If point is somewhere inside the quotes**

Using `expand-region`, the point does not need to be near the quotes. But in this case, you will need just few more (usually one or two more) key strokes.

Let's say the cursor position is as below now:

```
# cursor shown below is hiding the i character under it
ref = open('specif▮c-file-name')
```

Using the same binding as I used above:

- First time I hit `C-\` will select `specific`.
- Now I just need to hit `\` to expand the selection (`expand-region` feature). That will select `specific-file-name`.

  *If you had bound `er/expand-region` to `C-=`, hitting `=` again will do the incremental expansion. Read its documentation on how to binding keys for incremental expansion/contraction of selection.*
- Hitting `\` once more will select `'specific-file-name'`.
- Now you proceed with hitting `DEL` to delete the selection and then type `fname`. *If `delete-selection-mode` is enabled, you can skip the `DEL` stroke.*

In summary, with `delete-selection-mode` enabled, the key strokes look like: **`C-\\\fname`**.

[image]

---

### Using `change-inner`

I also came across [`change-inner`](https://github.com/magnars/change-inner.el) package by the `expand-region` author [**magnars**](https://github.com/magnars) (which uses `expand-region` as back-end) to do exactly what the Vim `ci` does (and also *change outer*).

From the package README:

> `change-inner` gives you vim's `ci` command, building on `expand-region`. It is most easily explained by example:
>
> ```
> function test() {
>   return "semantic kill";
> }
> ```
>
> With point after the word *semantic*
>
> `change-inner "` would kill the contents of the string
> `change-outer "` would kill the entire string
> `change-inner {` would kill the return-statement
> `change-outer {` would kill the entire block

Answer (score 5):

### With a region

To do this with a region, starting from:

```
ref = open(|'specific-file-name');
```

press <kbd>C-SPC C-b C-M-n C-b C-w</kbd>.

### Faster way

Starting from the point before paren, just like in Vim:

```
ref = open|('specific-file-name');
```

<kbd>C-M-k</kbd> (`kill-sexp`) will result in:

```
ref = open|;
```

If you have `electric-pair-mode` on, you can re-insert `()` with only <kbd>(</kbd>.
So the full key sequence is <kbd>C-M-k (</kbd> - not much longer than <kbd>ci(</kbd>.

Comment: Also, if the point is before the left quote, `ref = open(|'specific-file-name');`, `C-M-k` will give `ref = open(|);`. Quotes are also *balanced sexps*.

Comment: I was thinking of `delete-everything-inside-parens` sort of thing, not `delete-first-sexp-inside-parens`.

Comment: Nice solution but it requires me to move point before the expression I want to replace. The 'change inner' package works when point is anywhere inside the expression (same as vi).

Answer (score 1):

`evil` emulates most of Vim, and it does text objects out of the box.

In other words, with `evil` activated and using the default key bindings, `ci(` will do exactly what you're asking: change what's inside the enclosing parentheses.

More precisely, `ci(` will chain `evil-change` to `evil-inner-paren`.  You can also create your own arbitrary text objects as you like.

Comment: I know about evil (I've used it for a while now). I would like to know how this can be done in 'pure' emacs.

Comment: @kain88: fair enough: I figure there will be multiple answers to this question.  Out of curiosity, though, if you already use `evil`, why would you want the non-`evil` alternative?

Comment: (non-serious comment) @Dan He's probably preparing to come to the dark side.

Comment: I noticed that evil sometimes doesn't play well with other modes. Plus I'm curious to see how editing would be using just emacs

Answer (score 1):

### Using smartparens

**Kill**

1) Use `C-M-u` (`sp-backward-up-sexp`) to get out of `'` delimiters.

2) Use `C-0 C-M-k` (`0` prefix + `sp-kill-sexp`) to kill stuff inside current sexp or `C-k` (`sp-kill-hybrid-sexp`). The latter only works when `smartparens-strict-mode` is enabled and current sexp fits in one line.

```
ref = open('specific|-file-name')
// C-M-u
ref = open(|'specific-file-name')
// C-k
ref = open(|)
```

**Mark and delete/kill/copy**

1) Find your way to the beginning of sexp (in this example `C-M-u sp-backward-up-sexp` is enough), set mark `C-SPC` and go to the end of sexp with `sp-end-of-sexp`.

2) Then you can do whatever you wish: `C-w` to kill region, `M-w` to kill-ring-save (copy) region, `backspace` to delete it without cluttering kill ring (only with `delete-selection-mode`)

```
ref = open('specific|-file-name')
// C-M-u
ref = open(|'specific-file-name')
// C-SPC - mark is now active
ref = open(|'specific-file-name')
// sp-end-of-sexp (my binding: M-e)
ref = open(<'specific-file-name'|)
// backspace
ref = open(|)
```

**Mark-inside-sexp function**

`smartparens` package has `sp-mark-sexp` function that marks whole next sexp, i.e. delimiters and stuff between them.

You could use a function like this to throw delimiters out of the selection:

```
(defun mark-inside-sexp-using-sp ()
  (interactive)
  (sp-mark-sexp)
  (exchange-point-and-mark) (backward-char)
  (exchange-point-and-mark) (forward-char)
  (message "MARK INSIDE SEXP (using sp)"))

(global-set-key (kbd "s-SPC") 'mark-inside-sexp-using-sp)
;; this is "super" modifier (win key) with space
```

Get out of your sexp using `C-M-u` repeatedly and fire mark-inside-sexp-using-sp and then decide what to do with active region.